How to make parallel use null(empty) when there's not enough arguments with `--link`?
the command is something like this:
parallel --link echo ::: A B C ::: 1 2 3 4 5 ::: X O

The result is
| A | 1 | X |
| B | 2 | O |
| C | 3 | X |
| A | 4 | O |
| B | 5 | X |


But I want the result like this:
| A | 1 | X |
| B | 2 | O |
| C | 3 |   |
|   | 4 |   |
|   | 5 |   |


Is it possible?

how about just echo ::: A B C '' '' ::: 1 2 3 4 5 ::: X O '' '' ''?

no, the arguments are for demo, it's actually read from files. I want to combine 3 files line by line,  and leave empty space if there's no corresponding line.

then, why not state your intent rather than something else, it just confusing

Because I know how to solve that problem using other commands. parallel is the first command I tried, I want to know if it can also do the job.
